# Can't handle an ImportError calling matplotlib.use

Tags: python, matplotlib, exception

I'm trying to write a plotting code using matplotlib that works with interactive backends when possible and with non-interactive backend, when I work via SSH. I know that one can change a backend with `matplotlib.use('Agg')` and I tried to use python exception handling to choose the proper backend automatically, but I can't catch an ImportError properly.

This is what I tried:

```
try:
    matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
except ImportError:
    matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

and I still get the ImportError:

```
(...)

from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
ImportError: cannot import name _macosx
```

Any idea why `except ImportError` doesn't catch the error?

Comment: I am supposing you are using *Python 3*, try to see if you have `_macosx.so` under the usual path `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends`. Note that your version of Python might be different.

Comment: I use Python 2.7 and I don't have MacOSX on the computer I tried. I'm not surprised that I have Import Error, but I believe the except ImportError should handle this.

Comment: Search if you have the `_macosx.so` file somewhere in the `matplotlib` module...

Comment: I want this code to work even if I don't have - this is a reason why I'm trying to use "try/expect"

Comment: Are you surrounding the `from matplotlib.backends import _macosx` with a `try ... except` or not?

Comment: I didn't because I understand that `matplotlib.use('MacOSX')` calls it - this work on my Mac! After your suggestion I tried  `from matplotlib.backends import _macosx` within `try ... except` before using `matplotlib.use()`.  I had now warning `matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.`

Comment: So you call it before `pylab` or `pyplot`...